# Unable to run certain methods using Databricks extension within Visual Studio Code (Databricks Connect V2)

Tags: pyspark, vscode-extensions, azure-databricks, databricks-connect, databricks-vscode-extension

Following the instructions found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/vscode-ext/dev-tasks/databricks-connect, when I try to run the example codes provided (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/vscode-ext/tutorial) in particuarly the 'show' method , I get the following error code in my VS Code terminal. Same error happens when I run it using a jupyter notebook.

Just wondering if anyone has come across such issue and has resolved it?

Following are some of the key points worth mentioning:

1. The Databricks extension for VS Code I'm using is v1.1.3
2. I'm using python version 3.10.4 in a virtual environment which is aligned with my Databricks cluster python version
3. If I don't run the show() method but just simply print(type(customers)) or customers.printSchema() everything is fine and I get the right output within my VS Code terminal
4. I'm using the 'Run Python File' option when dealing with .py file and 'debug cell' option when dealing with .ipynb file which as per the link above is using Databricks Connect

**pyspark.errors.exceptions.connect.SparkConnectGrpcException: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
details = "Method not found: spark.connect.SparkConnectService/ReattachExecute"
debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {grpc_message:"Method not found: spark.connect.SparkConnectService/ReattachExecute", grpc_status:12, created_time:"2023-10-02T22:47:34.7298799+00:00"}"**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
   StructField('CustomerID', IntegerType(), False),
   StructField('FirstName',  StringType(),  False),
   StructField('LastName',   StringType(),  False)
])

data = [
   [ 1000, 'Mathijs', 'Oosterhout-Rijntjes' ],
   [ 1001, 'Joost',   'van Brunswijk' ],
   [ 1002, 'Stan',    'Bokenkamp' ]
]

customers = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
customers.show()
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. For me running the option `Upload and Run File on Databricks` works. Other options do not. I have also tested other methods that materialise a Dataframe like `count()` without success. For me `dbutils` methods also work.

I am using the following Databricks runtime: 13.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12)

Comment: @BartJoosten thanks for pointing that out; much appreciated. Which dbutils have you tried and worked? (I will test it out from my end)

Comment: what DBConnect version & what is the cluster version?

Comment: hi @AlexOtt it's good to hear from you. DBConnect version is 14.0.1 whereas cluster is 13.3LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of DB Connect should match the cluster version. It's actually mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect/python/install#requirements):

> **The Databricks Connect major and minor package version should match your Databricks Runtime version.** Databricks recommends that you always use the most recent package of Databricks Connect that matches your Databricks Runtime version. For example, when you use a Databricks Runtime 14.0 cluster, you should also use the databricks-connect==14.0.* package.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexOtt. Missed reading that bit of information. Upon aligning their versions, it worked; thanks once again.